# Modifying the data frame in R

Tags: r, data-structures, dataframe, tidyr

I have a data frame like that, composed by 500 rows and 60 columns.

```
   **%d1 %d2 %d3**
```

**pr1**  0.1   0.2    0.2

**pr2** 0.0   0.1    0.1

**pr3** 0.3   0.3    0.3

**pr4** 0.2   0.4    0.4

I want to make a row for each data in this way

```
 **%
```

pr1 0.1

pr1 0.2

pr1 0.2

pr2 0.0

pr2 0.1

pr2 0.1

pr3 0.2

pr3 0.4

.....

how can I do it?

Comment: It helps to make your question reproducible, use  dput(head(df)) to output a small sample of your df that others can use to help you with your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do  like this, using the libraries `dplyr` and `reshape2`. I also needed to create an Id column from presumed row.names:

Recreate your data:

```
df = data.frame(d1=c(0.1,0,0.3,0.2), d2=c(0.2,0.1,0.3,0.4), d3=c(0.2,0.1,0.3,0.4))
row.names(df) = c("pr1", "pr2", "pr3", "pr4")
```

Calculation: what's happenning is first we add the `id` column, then we "factorize" the dataframe, then I change the day in character to  numeric, and order by Id to get the same result as yours.

```
library(dplyr); library(tibble); library(reshape2)
df %>% rownames_to_column("id") %>% melt %>% mutate(day=as.numeric(variable)) %>% 
  select(id, day, pc_cum=value) %>% arrange(id)
####     id day pc_cum
#### 1  pr1   1    0.1
#### 2  pr1   2    0.2
#### 3  pr1   3    0.2
#### 4  pr2   1    0.0
#### 5  pr2   2    0.1
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. And what if I want to add another variable as a column? For example the presence of a video or not for each project, in which position should I add it in the Code?

Comment: Well, not sure I understand but if you have in your original data a 4rth column named `video` made of 0&1, you have to specify it in the `melt` arguments: `... %>% melt(id.vars=c("id", "vid")) %>% ...` and also add it in the select: `... %>% select(id, day, pc_cum=value, vid) %>% ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the melt() function from the [reshape2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/) package. It converts a data frame from wide from to long form.

```
D <- data.frame(
  c("pr1","pr2","pr3","pr4"),
  c(0.1,0.0,0.3,0.2),
  c(0.2,0.1,0.3,0.4),
  c(0.2,0.1,0.3,0.4)
)

colnames(D) <- c("id", 1:(ncol(D)-1))

library(reshape2) # for melt function
D2 <- melt(D, value.name="id")
```

Result:

```
> print(D2[order(D2$id),])
    id variable  id
1  pr1        1 0.1
5  pr1        2 0.2
9  pr1        3 0.2
2  pr2        1 0.0
6  pr2        2 0.1
10 pr2        3 0.1
3  pr3        1 0.3
7  pr3        2 0.3
11 pr3        3 0.3
4  pr4        1 0.2
8  pr4        2 0.4
12 pr4        3 0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different way:

```
data=data.frame(id=c("pr1","pr2","pr3","pr4"),
                d1=c(0.1,0,0.3,0.2),
                d2=c(0.2,0.1,.3,0.4),
                d3=c(0.2,0.1,0.3,0.4))
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
data%>%melt(id.vars="id")%>%group_by(id,value)%>%summarise(count=n())
```

Gives:

```
      id value count
  <fctr> <dbl> <int>
1    pr1   0.1     1
2    pr1   0.2     2
3    pr2   0.0     1
4    pr2   0.1     2
5    pr3   0.3     3
6    pr4   0.2     1
7    pr4   0.4     2
```

Answer (score 1):

The below version uses tidyr which is essentially reshape2 2.0, and is designed to work with the tidyverse suite of packages that include dplyr, ggplot2 etc.
The code gathers the data into long tidy form converting the variable headers into a new column but excluding the column "id".
the data is then arranged in id order but and the column that represents the previous headers dropped.

```
library(tidyr);library(dplyr)
 data %>% gather(., key="var", value="value", -id) %>% 
 arrange(id) %>%
 select(-var)
```

It may be sensible to keep the "var" column as it will allow greater flexibility with later processing or visualisation (e.g colouring by that column)